# How to show $\alpha\int_a^cf(x)dx+\beta \int_c^b f(x)dx =0$ means $f(x)=0$ everywhere $?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

**Question :**

Let $$f\ :\ [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$$   be  continuous . And  there  exist  constants  $\alpha$  $\beta$  such  that  $\forall c\in [a,b]$  $$\alpha \int_a^c f(x)dx +\beta \int_c^b f(x)dx =0 $$

Prove  that  $f=0$  allover  $[a,b]$.

**Attempt :**(*not* *much* *useful* )

Since  the  equation  holds  for  all  $c\in [a,b]$   , if  take  $c=a$  then  we  have $$\beta \int_a^b f(x)dx =0 $$ 
And  taking  $c=b$  we  get $$\alpha \int_a^b f(x)dx=0 $$

See  if  both  $\alpha=0$  and  $\beta=0$  hold  then  there  is  nothing  to  do . If  only  one  of  them  is  $0$   and  the  other  is  non-zero  then  from  the  last  two  equations  we  get $$\int_a^b f(x)dx =0 $$ and  this  does   not  ensure   $f$'s  being  identically  $0$  on  $[a,b]$ (for  example : $f(x)=sin x$  and $a=0$,$b=2\pi $ ) .

So  our  only  possibility  is  that  both $\alpha \neq 0$  and $\beta \neq 0$  must  hold .

Now  I  cannot  proceed  any  further  from  this  point . Please  give  me  some   hints  as  to  what  to  do  next .

Thaanks.

Comment: It is not true, take $\alpha=\beta = 0$. You need more conditions. For example, $\alpha \neq \beta$.

Comment: Well, if $\alpha = \beta$, then the expression reduces to $\int_a^b f(t) dt = 0$.

Comment: See also: [How to show $f(x)$ is $0$ in following problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3022358)

Answer (score 3):

If $\alpha  \neq \beta$, and we differentiate with respect to $c$, we get
$(\alpha-\beta)f(c) = 0$, from which we get $f(c) = 0$, hence $f = 0$ on $[a,b]$.

If $\alpha = \beta$, all we can conclude is that $\alpha \int_a^b f(x) dx = 0$, and so either $\alpha = 0$, or $f$ has zero average over $[a,b]$.

Comment: wow,  fantastic copper.hat

Comment: @RaziehNoori: Thanks, however it is a standard sort of trick, and I have been around long enough to see lots of them :-).

Comment: @copper.hat : Not  $0$  average, it requires $f$  to  be  identically  $0$ .For  $\alpha \neq 0$ , $\int_a^bf(x)dx=0$   does  not  give  that  as  you  can  see  in  my  post the  example  of  $sin x$ .

Comment: @user118494: I don't understand what you are trying to say. If $\alpha = \beta$ and $\alpha \neq 0$, all you can conclude its that $f$ has zero average. The example $\sin$ with $a=0, b = 2\pi$ demonstrates that. The function $\sin$ is not identically zero.

Comment: @copper.hat :  what  I  tried  to  mean   was  that  since  I  have  to  prove  that  $f$  is  identically  $0$   and  not "average $0$ "  so  may  be  we  should  cancel  the  possibility $\alpha=\beta $   as well , just  like  the  possibilities  "both $0$"  and  "exactly  one  of  them  $0$ "  were  cancelled.

Comment: If $\alpha = \beta$ then you **cannot** prove that $f=0$, as the $\sin$ example shows. If $\alpha \neq \beta$, then the result is true, as the above answer shows. (If $\alpha = 0$ and $\beta \neq 0$ then $f=0$, for example.)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to assume $\alpha \ne \beta$. Then if one defines $$g(x)=\alpha \int_{a}^{x}f(x)dx+\beta \int_{x}^{b}f(x) dx$$

then $g(c)=0$ for all $c \in [a,b]$. Thus $g$ is a constant and by fundamental theorem of calculus $g$ is differentiable. So $g'(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Thus $(\alpha-\beta)(f(x))=0$ and we are done

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Differentiate your equation with respect to $c$ and use the fundamental theorem of calculus. For $\alpha -\beta \neq 0$, you will then see the claim to be true.