# How to show $f(x)$ is $0$ in following problem?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $[a, b]$. Assume that there exist constants $α$ and $β$ with $(α ≠ β)$ such that
>   $$\alpha\int_a^x f(u)du + β\int_x^bf(u)du = 0 $$ for all $x$ belonging to $[a,b]$. Show that $f(x) = 0 $ for all $x$ belonging to $[a,b]$.

My attempt: if we take $x = a$, then we get $\int_a^bf(x)dx = 0$. However this does not imply $f(x)$ is $0$.

Comment: Amit.Differentiating(FTC): $\alpha f(x) -\beta f(x)=0$, for x in the interval. Can you proceed?

Comment: @PeterSzilas Thanks . I got it now .It basically involves second fundamental theorem of calculus .

Comment: So $f(x) = \beta - \alpha$.  The desired conclusion contradicts the assumption.

Comment: See also: [How to show $\alpha\int_a^cf(x)dx+\beta \int_c^b f(x)dx =0$ means $f(x)=0$ everywhere $?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1462024)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\alpha\int_a^xf(u)du+\beta\int_x^bf(u)du\right)=(\alpha -\beta)f(x)\end{align}

Comment: I got the hint .It involves second fundamental theorem of calculus .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\alpha \int_a^x f + \beta \int_x^b f = \beta\int_a^b f + (\alpha - \beta)\int_a^x f.
\end{align*}
In particular, setting $x= 0$ shows that $\int_a^bf = 0$. Thus $\int_a^x f$ for all $x\in[a, b]$. Since $f$ is continuous, it must vanish everywhere.